# Question about the count() method in Python

Tags: python

I was learning about the method in Python

[image]

I was wondering why does the code gives me 0, and not 2.

Thank you!

Comment: `'ee'.split()` gives you `['ee']` and `['ee'].count('e')` is 0. Why are you splitting in the first place? Just do `'ee'.count('e')` which gives you 2

Comment: do `print(a)` and you'll see

Comment: And please post your code as text; don't use screenshots.

Comment: `ee` count is 0 but `e` count is 2

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `split()` function. As you can read here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp, `split()` separates a string into a list and the default separator is a space. In "ee" is no space, so the function will return ["ee"] and in ["ee"] is no single "e".

If you want 2 as output you can do the following:

```
a = list(a_string)
count = a.count('e')
```

This should separate "ee" to ["e", "e"].